# 2019 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Unix & Linux's [third moderator election](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/3) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Kusalananda] [image: Jeff Schaller]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/election/3), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6012664968904704/0).

Comment: Thanks for linking to the Opavote summary report. It’s an informative explanation of how the votes were transferred after Kusulananda reached the quota. I was curious about how the threshold was calculated but after re-reading, I saw that the *Droop* formula was used, of which Wikipedia has a [good explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droop_quota).  Congratulations to Kusulananda and Jeff. I, for one, welcome our new multitasking, multiuser, Bell Labs-inspired overlords!

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan: Yes, that report is excellent. STV systems are more complicated than traditional vote counting systems, but having access to that sort of summary helps a ton.

Answer (score 22):

Welcome aboard guys! I only hope you won't regret it! >:)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QQBB3cwNM0#t=2m10

Comment: Thank you, and ditto! :)

Comment: Echoing Jeff, thanks and I hope so too :-)

Comment: Congratulations @Kusalananda and Jeff! :-)

Comment: Yay, my #1 and #2 votes won ;-)  They've definitely got more patience than me for some of the more problematic edge cases caused by an open community like this!

Answer (score 21):

Thank you to everyone that considered nominating themselves, as well to Arcabard, cnst, ilkkachu, and Kusalananda who decided to actually put themselves up for consideration. I said it in the chat for this election -- and I believe it in general -- that having a variety of choices leads to a better outcome. Special congratulations to Kusalananda who (deservedly) won nearly twice as many votes as I did, and so I look forward to doing half as much work as he does ;)

A special thank you to Stephen Kitt for his question "What’s it like being a Unix & Linux moderator?" and to terdon, slm, and Michael Mrozek for taking time to answer it. It was a huge help to me to learn about the benefits and challenges of being a moderator while I was deciding whether to nominate myself or not.

Thank you to Jon Ericson and Grace Note their help in this election, in particular for putting out the Question Collection and follow-up Questionnaire, and to everyone who submitted questions for it:

- Faheem Mitha
- JdeBP
- K7AAY
- Tim
- Tomasz
- Undercat
- and yes, even Fabby :)

I think threads like these are important because they call out what the community feels is important -- both for site and in a moderator. An open discussion thread like that is a great place for nominees to be able to expand on their ideas and for the community to get a better sense for how the nominees would perform the moderation tasks. Thank you also to JNat for opening up the separate Election chat room so that the community could haven even more discussion around the election and the candidates.

Finally, personal thanks to everyone who expressed support for me, both on the nomination page and in the chat rooms. Seeing comments on (all of) the nominations tells me that people care enough about the site to consider the nominees carefully. It was rewarding to see the comments that were directly supportive of the work I’ve done. I look forward to learning *even more* about how the site works, and to helping keep the site clean, positive, and moving forward together!